# Como cargar una imagen al dar clic en un marcador de un mapa

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Tengo el siguiente codigo con tres marcadores, como es posible que al momento de dar clic en alguno de los marcadores se cargue una imagen?

```js
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Tj</h4>Lat:32.509604, Lon:-117.020600', 32.509604, -117.020600, "<div><img width='254' height='355' src='http://descubretijuana.com/sites/default/files/mainrotatorpanoramica.jpg'</div>"],
  ['<h4>Rm</h4>Lat:32.565038, Lon:-116.021757', 32.565038, -116.021757, "<div> <img width='254' height = '355' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/LaRumorosa.jpg/220px-LaRumorosa.jpg'</div>"], 
  ['<h4>Mxl</h4>Lat:32.624473, Lon: -115.452642', 32.624473, -115.452642, "<div> <img width='254' height='355' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/MexicaliMetroNight.jpg/275px-MexicaliMetroNight.jpg'</div>"]
  ];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
        var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
  
var icons = [
  iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
  iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',     
          
           ]
var iconsLength = icons.length;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 5,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.0076, -115.708),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  panControl: false,
  //zoom: 14,                        // set the zoom level manually
  zoomControl: true,
  scaleControl: true,
  scrollwheel: false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
          }
        });
        

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  maxWidth: 160
        });

var markers = new Array();
  
var iconCounter = 0;
  
        // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
  map: map,
      icon: icons[iconCounter]
});

markers.push(marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }
})(marker, i));
          
iconCounter++;
          // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
  iconCounter = 0;
}
}

function autoCenter() {
  //  Create a new viewpoint bound
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  //  Go through each...
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
    bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
  }
  //  Fit these bounds to the map
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
autoCenter();
```

```css
html,
body,
#map{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible con el metodo `setIcon`:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
        marker.setIcon("ruta de la imagen");
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
       }
    })(marker, i));
```

Otra forma de hacerlo es poniendo código html en el atributo `content` del `infowindow`:

```
var infoContent = "<img src='imagen.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px;'>";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 160,
    content: infoContent
});
```

**Nota adicional**: La secuencia del html es incorrecta:

```
<div>
    <img width='254' height='355' src='http://descubretijuana.com/sites/default/files/mainrotatorpanoramica.jpg'
</div>
```

Lo correcto es:

```
<div>
    <img width='254' height='355' src='http://descubretijuana.com/sites/default/files/mainrotatorpanoramica.jpg'>
</div>
```

Actualización:
 El problema es que no estas pasando la imagen como argumento del `infoWindow`

```
 infowindow.setContent("<div>"+locations[i][0]+locations[i][1]+"</div>");
```

Después de esto lo único por lo que debes preocuparte es de dar el estilo necesario para que el texto y la imagen aparezcan.

```js
var locations = [
  ['<h4>Tj</h4>Lat:32.509604, Lon:-117.020600', 32.509604, -117.020600, "<div><img width='254' height='355' src='http://descubretijuana.com/sites/default/files/mainrotatorpanoramica.jpg'></div>"],
  ['<h4>Rm</h4>Lat:32.565038, Lon:-116.021757', 32.565038, -116.021757, "<div> <img width='254' height = '355' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/LaRumorosa.jpg/220px-LaRumorosa.jpg'></div>"], 
  ['<h4>Mxl</h4>Lat:32.624473, Lon: -115.452642', 32.624473, -115.452642, "<div> <img width='254' height='355' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/MexicaliMetroNight.jpg/275px-MexicaliMetroNight.jpg'></div>"]
  ];

// Setup the different icons and shadows
        var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';
  
        var icons = [
          iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
          iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',     
          
           ]
        var iconsLength = icons.length;

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.0076, -115.708),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          streetViewControl: false,
          panControl: false,
          //zoom: 14,                        // set the zoom level manually
          zoomControl: true,
          scaleControl: true,
          scrollwheel: false,
          disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
          zoomControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
          }
        });
        
        var infoContent = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/LaRumorosa.jpg/220px-LaRumorosa.jpg' style='width:50px;height:50px;'>";
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          maxWidth: 160,
                                  content: infoContent
        });

        var markers = new Array();
  
        var iconCounter = 0;
  
        // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
                               //alert (locations.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
         map: map,
         icon: icons[iconCounter]
          });

          markers.push(marker);

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
         return function() {
           "<div>"+locations[i][0]+locations[i][1]+"</div>"
           infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
          })(marker, i));
          
          iconCounter++;
          // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
          if(iconCounter >= iconsLength) {
           iconCounter = 0;
          }
        }

        function autoCenter() {
          //  Create a new viewpoint bound
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          //  Go through each...
          for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
           bounds.extend(markers[i].position);
          }
          //  Fit these bounds to the map
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        autoCenter();
```

```css
html,
body,
#map{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: @Houdini actualizado

Comment: no funciono companero @renelimon

Comment: no se si tenga que ver pero tu estructura de los html esta incompleta:

Comment: modifique el codigo a manera mas visual, para que se entendiera mejor el problema @renelimon

Comment: gracias eso amplia mucho mas el panorama de lo que tenia duda, Pero si deseara que se cargara una imagen diferente en cada marcador tengo que agregar otro `var infoContent` ?

Comment: esta respuesta podría servirte también http://stackoverflow.com/a/15140676/4987172